# Issues with the c# datarow

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a small problem with the c# DataRow Command in my code. Because when im trying to loop trough my mysql database and i have the foreach like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in _login._database)

    {

        //And search for Username and Pass that match

        if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(username) && row.ItemArray[1].Equals(password))

        {

            _usernameTextBox.Text = String.Empty;

            _passwordTextBox.Text = String.Empty;

            MessageBox.Show("Login Success");

           break;

        }

        //If not, then show this message.

        else

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Username/Password incorrect");

            break;

        }

    }
```

This error will come up:

```
Error   1   Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Data.DataRow'
```

Can someone help/explain to me what im doeing wrong.

This is the rest of the code:

```
namespace Chat
{
    public partial class StartupForm : Form
    {
        private LoginConnect _login = new LoginConnect();

        public StartupForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _login.OpenConnection();
        }

        private void _loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = _usernameTextBox.Text;
            string password = HashPass(_passwordTextBox.Text);

            //Loop through database

    foreach (DataRow row in _login._database)

    {

        //And search for Username and Pass that match

        if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(username) && row.ItemArray[1].Equals(password))

        {

            _usernameTextBox.Text = String.Empty;

            _passwordTextBox.Text = String.Empty;

            MessageBox.Show("Login Success");

           break;

        }

        //If not, then show this message.

        else

        {

            MessageBox.Show("Username/Password incorrect");

            break;

        }

    }



            _login.LoginQuery(username, password);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var register = new RegisterForm();
            register.ShowDialog();
        }

        public string HashPass(string password)
        {
            MD5 mdvijf = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            //compute hash from the bytes of text

            mdvijf.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));

            //get hash result after compute it

            byte[] result = mdvijf.Hash;

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits

                //for each byte

                strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            return strBuilder.ToString();


        }

    }
}
```

LoginCOnnect.cs:

```
namespace Chat
{


    class LoginConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection _connection = new MySqlConnection();
        private string _server;
        public string _database;
        private string _uid;
        private string _password;
        //public String MessageRecieved;
        private StringList _messagelist = new StringList();
        //private string _table = "logingegevens";
        private string _port;
        //private bool succes = false;


        public LoginConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }


        public void Initialize()
        {
            _server = "localhost";
            _port = "3307";
            _database = "testlogin";
            _uid = "root";
            _password = "usbw";

            string connectionString = "Server=" + _server + ";" + "Port=" + _port + ";" + "Database=" +
                               _database + ";" + "Uid=" + _uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + _password + ";";

            _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server");
                        break;

                    case 1042:
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password");
                        break;
                }
                return false;

            }


        }

        public void LoginQuery(string username, string password)
        {
            string loginquery = "SELECT * FROM logingegevens WHERE Username='" + username + "'AND Password='" + password + "';";

            try
            {

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(loginquery, _connection);

                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Succesfull");
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Acces denied");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username or passowrd is not correct.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `_login._database`?

Comment: As you can see _login is an private LoginConnect _login = new LoginConnect

Comment: Ans _database is a public string in LoginConnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in this statement

```
foreach (DataRow row in _login._database)
```

you are looping through a `string`, and so the enumeration of `_login._database` is an `IEnumerable` of `chars` and not of `DataRow`, so `row` variable would be a `char` and not a `DataRow`.

I suggest you to retrieve the data into an internal DataTable, your LoginConnect code would be like this:

```
namespace Chat
{    
    class LoginConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection _connection = new MySqlConnection();
        private string _server;
        public string _database;
        private string _uid;
        private string _password;
        private StringList _messagelist = new StringList();
        private string _port;
        private DataTable _dataTable;

        public LoginConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public DataTable Data
        { get { return _dataTable; } }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            _server = "localhost";
            _port = "3307";
            _database = "testlogin";
            _uid = "root";
            _password = "usbw";

            string connectionString = "Server=" + _server + ";" + "Port=" + _port + ";" + "Database=" +
                               _database + ";" + "Uid=" + _uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + _password + ";";

            _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        public bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server");
                        break;

                    case 1042:
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void LoginQuery(string username, string password)
        {
            string loginquery = "SELECT * FROM logingegevens WHERE Username='" + username + "'AND Password='" + password + "';";
            try
            {
                 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(loginquery, _connection);
                 MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 _dataTable = new DataTable();
                 adp.Fill(_dataTable);
                 var count = _dataTable.Rows.Count;   
            } 
            catch{}//your handling   
        }
    }
}
```

So you can loop through `Data`:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in _login.Data.AsEnumerable())
```

Comment: But i need the datarow for row.ItemArray, Maybe you can tell me another optoin that will work

Comment: Thanks but i got 2 errors from this. This are the errors: `Error 2 The name 'count' does not exist in the current context` `Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataTable' because 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: Already edited, copy the new code, and also you have to include System.Data.DataSetExtension into your project

Comment: Thankyou very much, Only i get 1 warning: `Warning 1 Field 'Chat.LoginConnect._dataTable' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null 
`

Comment: I've added the datatable initialization inside the LoginQuery method

Comment: and what will that do

Comment: It will get al the data from your connection and put it into a datatable, so you can loop through the table using the foreach

Comment: and then remove the initialize at the top?

Comment: No, you have to maintain the initialization, you have to call OpenConnection AND LoginQuery before looping through the datatable

Comment: can you show me what you said in the code? Because the loop works but it doesnt start on the if statement

Comment: And do ihave to do something with the var count?

Comment: And dont i have to run the command, Because count is always 0

Answer (score 0):

THis line is wrong: `(DataRow row in _login._database` because `_database` is type of string. You have to iterate over something that have `DataRow` like `DataTable`.

Anyway I would change your code to this:

```
private void _loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string username = _usernameTextBox.Text;
        string password = HashPass(_passwordTextBox.Text);

        if (_login.LoginQuery(username, password))
        {
            _usernameTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            _passwordTextBox.Text = String.Empty;

            MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username/Password incorrect");
        }
}
```

and LoginCOnnect.cs method `LoginQuery` to return `bool`

```
public bool LoginQuery(string username, string password)
{
    string loginquery = "SELECT * FROM logingegevens WHERE Username='" + username + "'AND Password='" + password + "';";

    try
    {

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(loginquery, _connection);

        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }                           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return false;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still have a smaal question. In the errorlist the error shows up: Chat.LoginConncet.LoginQuery(string,string) not all code paths return a value.  Where do i put my return